# Prevent SWF from stretching when opened in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, browser, haxe, stretch

When you open an SWF in your browser, it usually stretches to fit the whole screen. I want to prevent this from happening. That is, when the SWF is opened, it'll just appear in the browser at it's proper size, either in the top left or centre.

I understand that this can be done in an HTML page, and also when using the standalone player it will open in its proper size. However, I wish to deploy this as a SWF on its own, and chances are that the user will open it in their browser.

So yeah, is there any way to prevent this behaviour? I'm using Haxe, but AS3 code would be helpful as well. I've tried to set `stage.scaleMode` to `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`, but that doesn't help.

Comment: it's strange, stage.scaleMode must do the trick. Do you load other swf inside your main swf or something like that ?

Comment: @Binou: Nope. It is strange. It could be because I'm using Haxe, and/or the HaxePunk engine, but as far as I know, I'm accessing the base stage.

Comment: do you set it before or after the initialisation of your engine ? maybe the engine do something after ?

Comment: try this solution [HaxePunk stage.scaleMode - no effect](http://www.openfl.org/community/programming-haxe/stage.scalemode-no-effect/)

Comment: @Binou: I set it after the engine is initialised. I also took a look and the engine itself even sets it to `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`, as well as `HXP.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT` and `HXP.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL`. I also saw that solution before, but it doesn't help much; the issue was something else than `HXP.stage.scaleMode` not working.

Comment: that's because HaxePunk have his own way of managing displayObjects I think you you have to ask on HaxePunk forums, it's not an as3 problem

Comment: Yup, that was it. I've written the answer, I'll accept it once I can (in 8 hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it was something with HaxePunk, the engine I was using. I managed to fix it by putting this in the main class (which extends `Engine`):

```
HXP.screen.scaleX = HXP.screen.scaleY = 1;
```

In most other cases though, Lukasz's answer should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Use align and scaleMode

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

also in the html wrapper you may wish to set:

```
<script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script>
    var flashvars = {
    };
    var params = {
        menu: "false",
        scale: "noScale",
        allowFullscreen: "true",
        allowScriptAccess: "always",
        bgcolor: "",
        wmode: "direct" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
    };
    var attributes = {
        id:"layoutmanager"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "layoutmanager.swf", 
        "altContent", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", 
        "expressInstall.swf", 
        flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
<style>
    html, body { height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
    body { margin:0; }
</style>
```

otherwise without looking at your code it is hard to predict what you have that prevents scaling - or simply you misunderstand and it actually is using full browser size but SWF is not stretched but fills out the space.

Comment: Thanks! Even though this doesn't help for my specific problem, it does indeed work for most cases.